# Splinter fill function is very slow, with IE Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, browser, splinter

So, I've followed this tutorial to use the Splinter framework with Internet Explorer (https://stirunagari.wordpress.com/2017/08/20/using-internet-explorer-web-driver-with-splinter-framework/), and It's working....well kind of working.

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser('iexplorer')
browser.visit('http://google.com')
browser.fill('q', 'Text to fill in the search bar')
```

The search field is being filled but at a very slow rate, like 1 keystroke in 1-2 seconds. While using Chrome or Firefox as the browser the browser.fill is working well.
I know that this issue is most probably because IE is not directly supported by Splinter, but maybe someone knows a workaround or something?

***Edit***: I don't know what IEDriver I was using before, but I replaced it with IEDriverServer_Win32 from [Here](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.8/),and it's working fine now. I can't answer my question because someone deleted my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't using the latest Internet Explorer WebDriver; Updated it from here and it's working fine now:
http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.8/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using 32-bit version of IE Driver. You should use 64 bit version of IE driver not sure why but it much more faster.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18195373)

Comment: @ClausWilke Is he supposed to upload the driver here? The link is a link to the 64-bit driver.

Comment: This is the standard phrasing that SO uses in review; there are only so many options I can choose. Seems like a thin response to me either way. Maybe provide additional explanation of what is going on and why he thinks it's the driver? Also maybe explain how to find the driver more generally? The link currently goes to the latest version, but for how long will that be correct?